# Почему, если не закрывать строчки цикла знаком ";" в языке 1С, синтаксическая ошибка не обнаруживается и код прекрасно работает?

Tags: 1с

[image: Код, написанный без использования точек с запятой]

[image: Код автора курса]

Код, написанный без использования точек с запятой (рис. 1)

Код автора курса, содержащий ";" (рис. 2)

Автор курса часто использует точку с запятой, исходя из правил синтаксиса, но я убедился, что и без них всё работает, хотя по опыту других языков программирования знаю, что часто строчку нужно закрывать ";"

Comment: Не знаю точно с чем это связано, но замечено еще со времён Паскаля, что точку-с-запятой можно не ставить если следующий оператор "закрывающая-скобка" (End в паскале, КонецПроцедуры/Функции в данном случае)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В данном случае у тебя не возникает ошибки, так как твоя конструкция крайняя в процедуре. Если не ставить точку с запятой в самой последней строчке кода в процедуре/функции - программа не будет ругаться.

Если сделать так, то поругается:

```
Процедура Пример()
    
    Если Истина Тогда
        Сообщить("Пример 1");
    КонецЕсли

    Если Истина Тогда
        Сообщить("Пример 2");
    КонецЕсли;
    
КонецПроцедуры
```

Вот так не поругается:

```
Процедура Пример()
    
    Переменная1 = 10;
    
    Если Истина Тогда
        Сообщить("Пример 2");
    КонецЕсли;
    
    Переменная1 = 10
    
КонецПроцедуры
```